# What happen to the disk when an application saving big file

Tags: hard-disk, hardware, ssd

I'm curious about, when we work with files those need frequently saving  (eg. doc, pptx), what happen to the disk when we press the save button?

I was thinking about, the original file content should have been in aligned state in disk, let says we insert one character in middle of somewhere in the file and save it, in the most naive way I can think about is to wipe out all the old data in disk and write **all** the full new data again into the disk, it is ok to do if the file content is small, but what if the file is very big, let says 100 MB, it would be so inefficient.

In my case, I need to save large pdf files frequently (after adding highlights and annotations), what exactly the computer does when we save a file like this?

Comment: It's written as a new file. When the writing program issues the `close` (`man -a close`), the original file is returned to free space, unless the program renames the original to a backup.

Answer (score 0):

All depends of the program used.

Old MS office created a new file and renamed it on normal save, but it had a option for quick save that would append to the existent file a "override" info, that would change previously loaded info (say replacing a word in the X line, character position Y)

So some programs will simply create a new file and replace, others edit directly the file position, while others work like a database, where they can change the file structure (free blocks, add new one) to match what is needed. Then you have a mix, some have more complex setups, like a saved file to several components (like a ODF file, it is just a zip),  change each needed component and then construct a new merged document or update only the changed components (like updating a file in a zip)

So there is no size fits all and more complex programs usually use database like structures, that can move blocks around and the internal structure is decoupled from the real format. Those that the file format much match the document structure, usually recreate and rename the file is simpler.

Some programs change their behaviour, vim for example change the way it works when the file is small (work in a temporary file, so basically recreate and move) and bigfile (direct change the original file, no backup and other limitation)

IIRC, PDF have several layers and several of those layers can be changed "database" like, directly, without touching other parts